# Unable to connect to MongoDB server

Tags: server, 18.04, mongodb

I’m new to MongoDB server. I have installed the MongoDB server 3.6.6 in my system. When I try to connect to the MongoDB server, it shows the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-08-08T10:57:20.242+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-08-08T10:57:20.242+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

When I checked and tried to start the MongoDB service, I got the following status:

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: `perror 14` says `OS error code  14:  Bad address`. It loogs to me as if you don't have `mongodb-server` installed, configured or started.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).